# Setting project name "debug_msgs" occurs error while "mydebug_msgs" is ok

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-bouncy, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I build my msg project whose name is "debug_msgs" with ros2 bouncy, I get error as follow:

command:

```
   colcon build
```

output:

```
Starting >>> debug_msgs
--- stderr: debug_msgs                         
CMake Error at /root/ros2_ws/install/ament_cmake_export_libraries/share/ament_cmake_export_libraries/cmake/ament_export_libraries.cmake:56 (message):
  ament_export_libraries() package 'debug_msgs' passes the build
  configuration keyword 'debug_msgs__rosidl_generator_c' as the last exported
  library
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /root/ros2_ws/install/rosidl_generator_c/share/rosidl_generator_c/cmake/rosidl_generator_c_generate_interfaces.cmake:171 (ament_export_libraries)
  /root/ros2_ws/install/ament_cmake_core/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_execute_extensions.cmake:38 (include)
  /root/ros2_ws/install/rosidl_cmake/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:169 (ament_execute_extensions)
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)


---
Failed   <<< debug_msgs [ Exited with code 1 ]

Summary: 0 packages finished [1.21s]
```

but after I changed the project name to "mydebug_msgs", It goes well, could any one tell me why ?
the test demo is : https://github.com/lxbeyond/bouncy_msg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299980/setting-project-name-%22debug_msgs%22-occurs-error-while-%22mydebug_msgs%22-is-ok/) by [lxbeyond](https://answers.ros.org/users/36253/lxbeyond/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CMake uses a few keyword to identify libraries with special semantic: `debug`, `optimized`, and `generic`.

The code was supposed to only detect those but it turns out the regex was incorrect and matches the library in your case (starting with `debug`).

Please see the following PR which fixes the regex and allows you to build your package as expected: https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/pull/148

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't had a chance to look into it. But I'd suspect that your choice of `debug` as a name is likely colliding with a keyword at one of the layers.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1